# Установка Android приложения

Tags: android

Как установить своё приложение на телефон с ОС Android?

Comment: что такое аппликация? я это слово только в контексте "техника творчества" знаю. Может вы имели в виду приложение?

Comment: Ну... Просто поместите на телефон и откройте на нём же ваш `*.apk` файл...

Answer (score 1):

1. Подсоединяешь телефон в USB-порт ПК.
2. Тыкаешь по проекту своему и ищешь зеленую стрелочку, она добро дает на запуск.
3. Ждешь пока приложение установится и запустится автоматически на Ваше устройство.
4. Если телефона нет, то пройдите по ссылке, которую я дал, там рассказывается про то, как установить *AVD* (эмулятор) телефонов на *Android*.
5. Если скорость *AVD* не устраивает, то установите [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)

Изучите [данный](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/12-urok-3-sozdanie-avd-pervoe-prilozhenie-struktura-android-proekta.html) урок. Если вопросы останутся пишите.

В конце очень много полезных ссылок для начинающих. [Изучите их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info), полезно.

Comment: Старайтесь ответ писать содержательно, а ссылку приводить, как источник. Ссылка может быть не рабочей через некоторое время и ответ будет бесполезен для сообщества.

Comment: Спасибо, и сылки очень полезны.

Comment: @Maic рад был помочь:)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы программист и пишите свою программу (или у вас чья то чужая программа) то включите режим разработчика:
"Заходим в меню настроек и ищем там раздел «О телефоне» — тяпаем (касаемся) пальцем. Потом скролим вниз и видим «Номер сборки», тяпаем по нему семь раз."
Затем в меню настроек идете в Безопасность и там разрешаете установку приложений не из Google Play

Дальше переносите ваш apk файл на телефон и запускаете сей файл